# libGDX : change Scroll position of scroll pane

Tags: java, libgdx

**I**n my code the `y` scroll position in pixels is the top of the scroll pane :

```
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(480, 800));
    Image map = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets-levels/map.png")));
    scrollpane = new ScrollPane(map, new ScrollPaneStyle());
    scrollpane.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(scrollpane);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

**How** can I change `y` scroll position in the bottom of scroll pane ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a class named `MyScrollPane` which would be copied from `ScrollPane`.
2. Add this line `myScrollpane.amountY = map.getHeight();`